# hibernate SQL in IBM Integration BUS (IIB) - config log4j without its plugin

Tags: hibernate, log4j, broker

I want to use hibernate in IBM IIB. MY problem is to see the SQL query that would be run by hibernate. Is it possible to see hibernate query in my_execution_group stdout? or I should config log4j for that?

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration().  
        setProperty("show_sql","true").
        setProperty("format_sql","true").
        setProperty("use_sql_comments","true").
```

for seeing the query in my_execution_group stdout, I copy sl4j.jar file in shared-classes direcoty. and load my log4j config file by `mqsichangeproperties broker -e ex -o ComIbmJVMManager -n jvmSystemProperty -v "-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/home/log4j.properties"` command but I could not see my sql query in stdout

Answer (score 0):

Normal practice among IIB devs is to use Log4J (or better, java.util.logging) for custom logging. You *can* get the stdout from an execution group (integration server) but that contains a lot of other stuff that you are not likely to be interested in.

re: your comment about using shared-classes...I find it much simpler to put Java code into a shared library. It makes it a lot simpler to deploy (you can just deploy the BAR file, instead of copying a jar file onto the server).